# Dataweave 2 How to map Object to JSON Arrays of Object

Tags: mule, dataweave

Have a JSON Object which I need to map to an array of objects but can't get the structure right after many tries. Would it be better, if the script gets very complex and damages readability and ease of maintenance, to have this process divided into to scripts instead of a one dataweave 2 script?

Current output:

```
{
  "batchId": "71f7a8534907940cb1b5",
  "status": "1",
  "products": [
    {
      "materialNumber": "9780429435942",
      "errorMessages": [
        "Failure",
        "Mistake"
      ],
      "materialNumber": "9780429435950",
      "errorMessages": [
        "Exception"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Desired output:

```
{
  "batchId": "71f7a8534907940cb1b5",
  "status": "1",
  "products": [
    {
      "materialNumber": "9780429435942",
      "errorMessages": [
        "Failure",
        "Mistake"
      ]
    },
    {
      "materialNumber": "9780429435950",
      "errorMessages": [
        "Exception"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

DW2 script:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var failedProducts = vars.response.materials filterObject ((product) -> product.status == "1")
---
{
    batchId: vars.batchId,
    status: vars.overallStatus,
    products: [
        failedProducts mapObject (value,key,index) -> {
            materialNumber: value.materialNumber,
            errorMessages: value.messages.*item.*msgText
        }
    ]
}
```

Source data:

```
<response>
    <overallStatus>1</overallStatus>
    <materials>
      <item>
        <status>0</status>
        <materialNumber>9781231231231</materialNumber>
        <messages>
          <item>
            <msgText>Success</msgText>
          </item>
        </messages>
      </item>
      <item>
        <status>1</status>
        <materialNumber>9780429435942</materialNumber>
        <messages>
          <item>
            <msgText>Failure</msgText>
          </item>
          <item>
            <msgText>Mistake</msgText>
          </item>
        </messages>
      </item>
      <item>
        <status>1</status>
        <materialNumber>9780429435950</materialNumber>
        <messages>
          <item>
            <msgText>Exception</msgText>
          </item>
        </messages>
      </item>
    </materials>
</response>
```

Comment: I am missing a few values to try it on my own (e.g. the variables) but if you change `errorMessages: value.messages.*item.*msgText` to `[errorMessages: value.messages.*item.*msgText[0]]` you maybe able to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem which you are facing is because XML does not **natively** support arrays. So while reading an XML using dataweave you need to explicitly mention that you want a certain path to be read as an array, which is exactly what you did when you wrote `value.messages.*item.*msgText` in your dataweave. You just need to do the same thing for the "item" element (which you are calling products).

This is the dataweave you are looking for:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var failedProducts = vars.response.materials.*item filter ((product) -> product.status == "1")
---
{
    batchId: vars.batchId,
    status: vars.overallStatus,
    products: failedProducts map (value) -> {
            materialNumber: value.materialNumber,
            errorMessages: value.messages.*item.*msgText
        }
 }
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Exactly what I needed. As you say, my main problem was an incorrect filter - was missing `.*item`

Comment: I think you dont need `.*msgText`. It could simply be .msgText cause `*item` already took care of it.

Comment: @Thinker-101 yes it is not needed, but it is a good idea to put that for better readability in future. Just by looking at it makes it clear that it is an array. But still, it depends on your preference.

Answer (score 1):

Here's code (different than yours) that give you the desired result:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var xml = '
<response>
    <overallStatus>1</overallStatus>
    <materials>
      <item>
        <status>0</status>
        <materialNumber>9781231231231</materialNumber>
        <messages>
          <item>
            <msgText>Success</msgText>
          </item>
        </messages>
      </item>
      <item>
        <status>1</status>
        <materialNumber>9780429435942</materialNumber>
        <messages>
          <item>
            <msgText>Failure</msgText>
          </item>
          <item>
            <msgText>Mistake</msgText>
          </item>
        </messages>
      </item>
      <item>
        <status>1</status>
        <materialNumber>9780429435950</materialNumber>
        <messages>
          <item>
            <msgText>Exception</msgText>
          </item>
        </messages>
      </item>
    </materials>
</response>
'
var data = read(xml,"application/xml")
var batchId = "71f7a8534907940cb1b5"
---
{
    batchId: batchId,
    status: data.response.overallStatus,
    products: 
        data.response.materials.*item filter ($.status as Number != 0)
        map {
            materialNumber: $.materialNumber,
            errorMessages: [$.messages.item]
        }
}
```

I did use DW variables instead of the `vars` you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var failedProducts = vars.response.materials filterObject ((value) -> value.status contains  "1")
---
{
    batchId: vars.batchId,
    status: vars.overallStatus,
    products: failedProducts.*item map (value) -> {
            materialNumber: value.materialNumber,
            errorMessages: value.messages.*item.msgText
        }
}
```